# How to maintain indexing in two lists after sorting only one?

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I have two lists of numerical values. Each index in one list needs to be kept at the same index in the other, even after I sort one of them (I want to sort one in ascending order, and graph each point in that list against a point in the other list). In other words, I need the order of indexing in both lists to change in the same way.

```
def Power():
    work_done = WorkDone()
    power = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(work_done):
        if sustained_data[i] != 0:
            power.append(round(work_done[i] / (sustained_data[i] * 60), 2))
        i += 1
    power.sort()

    return power
```

I would like to plot `power` against `sustained_data`, where each point in `sustained_data` correlates to a point in `power` (due to the fact that the former is used to calculate the latter).
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Didn't find that in searching, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Is it too costly to re-sort or re-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the first comment below my question links to a general solution, I managed to play around and determine that if you create a matrix of the two lists, and use the `sort()` function, the matrix indexes will be sorted according to the first sub index, much like sorting a standard list would work.

```
test1 = [11, 2, 1, 14, 8]
test2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
newtest = []
while i < len(test1):
    newtest.append(
        [test1[i], test2[i]]
    )
    i += 1

newtest.sort()
```

would output: `[[1, 3], [2, 2], [8, 5], [11, 1], [14, 4]]`

Perhaps this helps somebody down the road.